# Spotlight won't index /Applications

Tags: high-sierra, spotlight

I noticed some apps missing from Spotlight, so I tried to force a reindex by adding /Applications to the exclusion list, then removing it. Now it's even worse, as none of my apps are indexed. How do I force this the right way?

Comment: I'm really tempted to say, 'wait for Mojave'. It fixes a lot of things badly wrong with High Sierra/Sierra :/

Comment: is your SIRI enabled ?

Comment: when you say, "your" apps ? how about apple apps

Comment: I mean `/Applications`. And Siri is not enabled, I don't think. That doesn't seem relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Launch Terminal, and type or paste the following command:

```
sudo mdutil -E /
```

reindex the spotlight database for everything on the computer, (it might take a while)

Terminal may ask you for your password

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: could you tell me what Apps are missing ?

Comment: All of them....